# Аттрибуты в C#

Tags: c#, атрибуты

Здравствуйтею У меня вопрос по использованию атрибутов в C# Допустим у меня есть класс реализующий атрибут:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAttr : Attribute 
{
   // код
}
```

и класс который должен его использовать

```
public class Foo 
{
    [MyAttr]
    public void Bar() 
    {
        // вопрос: как мне использовать в этом методе описанный атрибут?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Доступ к атрибутам возможен лишь через reflection. Если вам надо в текущем методе сделать что-то с его атрибутом, делайте так:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
    }

    [MyAttr(WeirdParameter="some value")]
    [MyAttr(WeirdParameter="some another value")]
    static void Test()
    {
        var mi = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
        var attributes = mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttrAttribute));
        foreach (MyAttrAttribute attr in attributes)
            Console.WriteLine("Parameter: {0}", attr.WeirdParameter);
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple=true)]
public class MyAttrAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string WeirdParameter { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На [сайте](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sw480ze8.aspx) [мсдн](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tw5zxet9.aspx) есть информация по [атрибутам](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z919e8tw.aspx).